# implementing a generic binary function with a class and functor as template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I am trying to wrap some templated functions into some binary functors like below. When I try to compile the code I have the error

```
 error: no match for call to ‘(QtyAsc) (myobj&, myobj&)
```

I thought that being `operator()` in `QtyAsc` a function in a class, the template deduction mechanism would have worked but it seems that the compiler doesn't accept `myobj` classes as valid types for it.

Is it maybe because of the call to `boost::bind`? I was trying to provide a default implementation for the second templated argument (unfortunately I cannot use C++11 with default templated arguments).

```
  class myobj {
   public:
    myobj(int val) : qty_(val) {}
    int qty() { return qty_;}
   private:
    int qty_;
  };

  template<class T>
  int get_quantity(const T& o) {
    throw runtime_error("get_quantity<T> not implemented");
  }

  template<>
  int get_quantity(const myobj& o) {
    return o.qty();
  }

  struct QtyAsc {
    template<class T, class QEx >
    bool operator()(const T& o1, const T& o2, QEx extr = boost::bind(&get_quantity<T>,_1)) const {
      if(extr(o1) < extr(o2))
        return true;
      return false;  
    }
  };

  int main() {
   myobj t1(10),t2(20);

   QtyAsc asc;
    if(asc(t1,t2))
      cout << "Yes" << endl;
   }
```

Comment: `if (…) return true; return false;` → `return …;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use C++11, just provide an additional overload:

```
struct QtyAsc {
  template<class T, class QEx >
  bool operator()(const T& o1, const T& o2, QEx extr) const {
    return extr(o1) < extr(o2);
  }
  template<class T>
  bool operator()(const T& o1, const T& o2) const {
    return operator()(o1, o2, &get_quantity<T>);
  }
};
```

(I've omitted the unnecessary `boost::bind`.) Also, you will need to declare `myobj::qty` to be `const`:

```
int qty() const {
  return qty_;
}
```

since you want to invoke it on `const` objects. ([Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3328c88e36433a96))

Comment: I would prefer this even in C++11.  If you have `template<class T1, class T2=DfltType> void f(T1 o1, T2 o2 = dflt_arg);`, you probably don't want people doing `f<X,Y>(x)`.

Comment: HI Casey. Thanks a lot. Actually I like this trick i.e. having one more function capable of calling all defaults gives code a little touch of extra clarity..I don't mind putting few more lines. Can I ask you ultimate confirm? Is it because my code is suitable more for C++11  the only reason why the code is not building i.e. it is violating the current standard (no default in template args for function template)?